# Python: Generating all n-length arrays combinations of values within a range

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Ok. I'm looking for the smartest and more compact way to do this function

```
def f():
    [[a,b,c] for a in range(6) for b in range(6) for c in range(6)]
```

which should generate all the combinations for the values a,b,c like this:

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,0,2]
...
[1,0,0]
[1,0,1]
...
```

and so on...

But I want this to be flexible, so I can change the range or iterable, and also the length of the generated arrays. Range is an easy thing:

```
def f(min, max):
    [[a,b,c] for a in range(min,max) for b in range(min,max) for c in range(min,max)]
```

This is ok for 3-length arrays, but I'm thinking now of making 4-length arrays or 7-length arrays and generate all combinations for them in the same range.

It has to exist an easy way, maybe with concatenating arrays or nesting comprehension lists in some way, but my solutions seem to bee too much complex.

Sorry for such a long post.

Comment: The `itertools` module has a `product` function that does exactly what you're looking for. `from itertools import product; product(range(6), range(6), range(6))`. Whatever iterator is placed last cycles the fastest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which is just a convenience function for nested iterations. It also has a `repeat`-argument if you want to repeat the same `iterable` multiple times:

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> amin = 0
>>> amax = 2
>>> list(product(range(amin, amax), repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0),  (0, 1, 1),  (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

To get the `list` of `list` you could use `map`:

```
>>> list(map(list, product(range(amin, amax), repeat=3)))
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

However `product` is an iterator so it's really efficient if you just iterate over it instead of casting it to a `list`. At least if that's possible in your program. For example:

```
>>> for prod in product(range(amin, amax), repeat=3):
...     print(prod)  # one example
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: I finally made a one-liner with `[list(elem) for elem in product(*repeat(iterable, times))]`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def f(minimum, maximum, n):
    return list(product(*[range(minimum, maximum)] * n))
```

Drop `list` to return a generator for memory efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

*itertools* has everything you need. *combinations_with_replacement* will generate combinations of given length with repeating elements from given iterable. Note that returned value will be iterator.

```
def f(min, max, num):    
    return itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(min, max), num)
```

Comment: Nice for other situations, but I needed [0,0,1] != [1,0,0]. The order does matter. Maybe I should have explained better. I will write this down, though

Comment: Right, then as some other answers stated - itertools.product will be better.

Answer (score 1):

A pure python implementation :

```
k=2  # k-uples
xmin=2
xmax=5 
n=xmax-xmin

l1 = [x for x in range(n**k)]
l2 = [[ x//n**(k-j-1)%n for x in l1] for j in range(k)]          
l3 = [[ xmin + l2[i][j] for i in range(k)] for j in range(n**k)]
```

`l3` is :

```
[[2 2]
 [2 3]
 [2 4]
 [3 2]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]
 [4 4]]
```

Comment: You should review the code. *// gives a syntax error

Comment: One should rather call it "pure built-in" implementation. I find it non-pythonic because of unreadability and possibly more memory and time overhead than when done with functionality from Python's standard library.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is the cartesian product of the ranges. Luckily this already exists in itertools

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.product(range(0,5), range(0,5), range(0,5))))
```